# 同じファイルに対するリダイレクション追記は排他が必要ですか？

Tags: linux, bash

Linux の bash シェルで、複数プロセスで同時に実行されるシェルスクリプトから1つのファイルにログとして1行ずつ追記します。

順序は厳密である必要はなく、出力が欠けたり echo 文がエラーにならなければ良いです。

今は以下のようにログファイル自身で排他ロックを獲得して追記を実行することで、期待どおり動作します。

`flock -x logfile -c "echo hello >> logfile"`

ここで疑問なのは、このような場合でも flock は必要でしょうか？例えば

`echo hello >> logfile`

だけの場合、同時に複数のプロセスで実行されても、エラーになったり、出力が欠けるなど発生する可能性はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 補足です。flock する場合としない場合で、2 プロセスでループ実行しましたが、flock しなくても正常に出力されました。たまたまタイミングが重ならなかっただけなのか >> のリダイレクションは排他が不要なのか、確信が無かったので質問しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 回答

排他処理は不要だと思います。
Linuxでのechoなど標準出力への書き込みはシステムコールwriteを使っていますので、他のプロセスからの出力が重なっても結果が失われることはありません。

bashは標準出力をファイルにリダイレクトするとき、アペンドモードでファイルをopenしているのでファイルの末尾に追加されます。出力が混じることもないと思います。

---

以下調査結果です。

### スクリプト(q.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA >> q.txt
```

### straceの実行

```
strace bash ./q.sh
```

### 実行結果抜粋

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "q.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(1, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
write(1, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n", 24) = 24
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。O_APPEND で open して close までの間に、別のプロセスが open しにきたら、それも成功してしまうのでしょうか。または open が -1 で返り、後から開始した方がエラーになるのでしょうか。

Comment: 複数のプロセスが同じファイルをopenしてもエラーにはならないと思います。man -s2 openで確認してみましたが、複数のプロセスが同じファイルをopenしてもエラーになる記述はみつかりませんでした。

Comment: エラーにならないことでファイルポインタのシーク位置がそれぞれのプロセスで、必ずしもファイルの末尾にならないことなど問題が出るのではと思いました。

Comment: プロセスAでファイル末尾へlseek(シーク)してwriteするとき、その間でプロセスBがwriteするとプロセスAのwriteがファイル末尾にならないことは起きますが、O_APPENDでオープンしたときのwriteはその時点でのファイル末尾に書き込まれます。システムコールのwriteはカーネルで実行されるためwriteの途中で他のプロセスが割り込むことはありません。すべてのログ出力の処理がログファイルをO_APPENDでオープンしていればこの問題は発生しないと思います。

Comment: たしかに O_APPEND の場合は write の度に lseek する、かつ write はバイト列に対して1回の操作であることから、大丈夫そうにも思えます。記載いただいているとおり lseek と write 操作の間で、稀なタイミングで別のプロセスからファイルが更新される可能性があるかどうかですね。https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html によると lseek と write の間で "no intervening file modification" とあるので (他のプロセスからの場合も含んで書かれているのか微妙ですが) ファイルの変更は割り込まないようにも読めますね。おそらく、頂いたご回答から flock しなくても大丈夫なんだろうと思いますが（実際、私も長年システム開発や運用をやってきていますが、混ざった事例を見たことは無いのですが）、念のため flock を、今回はしようかなと思います。

Comment: クリティカルな業務であれば確実性重視は理解できます、flockの使用をやめた方がよいというつもりはまったくありません。しかしLinuxでログファイルが通常ファイルの場合にシステムコールのopen(O_APPEND)でwrite()の振る舞いがアトミックでないならば稀な現象といえども世界的な大問題だと思います。ログ出力を共通化し、確実にO_APPENDが使われることを保証することが現実的と考えました。ファイル出力はけして軽い処理ではないため、私はflock排他による遅延やデッドロック、flockもれを懸念します。※古いshでは>>をシークで実装しているものがあり、ログファイルの出力が入り乱れた経験があり、このときはtee -aを使って回避していました。

Answer (score 3):

出力が欠けることはありませんが、出力元のプログラムの動作によっては、行の途中でログが混じる可能性があります。ただし、条件やタイミングがかなりシビアなため、発生は極めて希だと考えられます。

---

以下は割り込みを確認するためのテスト用のプログラムです。(Rubyで書いていますが、ログファイルに書き込むところの`system`メソッドはシェルのリダイレクトが使用されます)

slow_print.rb

```
str = ('0'..'9').to_a.join + ('A'..'Z').to_a.join + ('a'..'z').to_a.join
str.each_char do |c|
  print c
  $stdout.flush
  sleep 0.1
end
puts
```

multi_rediret.rb

```
10.times.map do
  fork do
    system('ruby slow_print.rb >> test.log')
  end
end.each do |pid|
  Process.waitpid(pid)
end
```

上記二つのファイルを置き、Rubyがインストールされた環境で、`ruby multi_redirect.rb`と実行するとtest.logが書き込まれます。slow_print.rbのみ実行した場合は

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

の一行になります。`>>`によるリダイレクトションが排他処理を行うのであれば、上の行が10個書き込まれるはずですが、実際のtest.logは

```
000000000011111111112222...
```

というように、それぞれの間に挟み込まれた物になります。つまり、排他処理はされず、それぞれのプログラムは、それぞれ勝手なタイミングに書き込みを実行し、行が混じる事があります。

---

上のプログラムは一文字ずつ打つのに0.1秒待っており、その度フラッシュまでしています。これはわざと割り込みさせるためにしており、実際にはあまりないプログラムです(プログレスバーを表示する場合などでは使われていますが)。実際のプログラムは一行単位でフラッシュすることが多いです。そのためあ、一行を一回のシステムコールで書き込もうとします。その場合は、その処理の途中に割り込んで別のプロセスの書き込むことはありません。しかし、一回のシステムコールではバッファサイズ(Linuxの場合の標準は4096)までしか書き込めないため、書き込み量が多い場合は、一回で書き込まれず、他のプロセスにわりこまれる可能性はあります。(一行一行が短くても、複数行をまとめてフラッシュすると行の途中でシステムコールがわかれるといこともあり得ます。)

ということで、実際の所、行の途中で割り込まれるようなログになることは極めて希だと考えられます。また、ログは、基本的には、問題があったときの調査に使用するぐらいですが、ログの行が混じっていた場合でも、前後から本来の行を取り出すことは可能だと考えられます。しかし、ログ内容を分析集計する場合は、そのようなログが邪魔になってしまうことも確かです。そういった分析が前提であれば、別の方法(ログ出力は一つのプロセスだけがするようにするとか、syslog経由にするとか)を考える必要があります。

---

行の途中でログが混ざる例を見たことが無い人がほとんどかと思いますが、私は、一つだけそのようなログを吐き出す商用ソフトウェアを知っています。ただ、それはWebアプリケーションで、CGI(クローズドソースのバイナリ)で動くものでした。そのWebアプリケーションには認証などの機能があり、認証ログや動作ログ等が独自のログファイルに書き込むようになっていました。アクセス元の統計や分析のために認証ログを解析しようとしたときに、異常な行が希に現れる事があって、詳しく見ると行の途中でログが混じっているという物でした。ただ、発生は非常に希であり、統計的な分析には影響はほぼ無く、また、インシデント発生時の調査にも支障を来さなかったため、サポートへの不具合報告はしませんでした。

多数の利用者がいるWebアプリケーションのCGIであるため、同時実行はかなりの頻度で発生します。ソースコードが公開されていない商用ソフトウェアと言うことで詳細は不明ではありますが、行の途中で別のプロセスが割り込んだ結果だと考えられます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回 echo 文が 1 個だけなので、おっしゃるとおりかなり「稀な」タイミングであろうとは思います。しかしながら、今回、ログ出力の速度を求めていないため flock することの速度低下は許容内であり、かつ、行の途中での割り込み（混ざり）は極力避けたいので、明示的に flock する方向にしようかと思っております。ありがとうございます。

Comment: どうしても行の途中が混ざるのを避けたいというのであれば、私であれば、logger等を使ってsyslogに書き込むようにします。将来のことを心配されているようですが、もしflockを使うような今の方法を維持したままechoの所を別のプログラムにした場合、「ロック中に実行するプログラムが終了しなかった場合、他のプログラム全てがロックされてしまう」というリスクを背負うことになると思うからです。排他処理を組み込む場合、速度を心配する前に「全てが止まってしまう可能性」を心配すべきかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事が参考になるかと思います。

[Appending to a File from Multiple Processes](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/08/03/)

> Appending
>
> The first concern is solved by the operating system, with one caveat. On POSIX systems, opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag will guarantee that [writes always safely append](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html).
>
> > If the `O_APPEND` flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing the file offset and the write operation.
>
> However, this says nothing about interleaving. **Two processes successfully appending to the same file will result in all their bytes in the file in order, but not necessarily contiguously**.

ただし、NFS や HDFS では注意が必要とのことです。

> The caveat is that not all filesystems are POSIX-compatible. Two famous examples are NFS and the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). On these networked filesystems, appends are simulated and **subject to race conditions**.

Comment: ありがとうございます。Two processes successfully appending to the same file will result in all their bytes in the file in order, but not necessarily contiguously. だとしますと、hello が hlelo にはならないが、2 つのプロセスから出力すると helhellolo にはなり得ると読めます。安全のためには flock した方が安全かと思いました。

Comment: stderr の場合、デフォルトでは出力がバッファリングされていませんので、その様なことが発生するかもしれません。一方、stdout の場合はデフォルトで行バッファリングが行われますので、行単位で「混ざる」可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。stdout を使いますので今回は行内の混ざりが無ければ良いのですが、将来的にわたし以外のメンテナーが stderr を使う可能性など考えると、明示的に flock して待たせるほうが安心ですね。flock しようと思います。